# call forwarding in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know we can use *21*Phone Number# will make a call forwarding.i want to do this programmatically.Here is my code.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:*21*09043137902#"]];
```

But not working..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did u got the solution??? I am trying to do same thing, but hvnt got successeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application automatically blocks all tel: scheme urls that contain * or # to avoid malicious applications from forwarding calls. See Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1