# Conditional call forwarding

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to forward calls in i-phone programatically. I tried like *21*Phone number#
to forward call.when ever i make a call using this code to a normal number it is working .but when ever i adding *21* it is not working.This is the possibilities i tried.

```
    -(IBAction)two
       {
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://*21*+91 90-43-137902#"]];
NSString *phoneNumberString=@"*21*90-43-137902#";
NSString *phoneLinkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];


       }
     -(IBAction)three
       {
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://*21*09043137902#"]];

NSString *phoneNumberString=@"*21*9043137902#";
NSString *phoneLinkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];


       }
     -(IBAction)four
        {
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:*21*09043137902#"]];

NSString *phoneNumberString=@"*21*09043137902#";
NSString *phoneLinkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];

      }

   -(IBAction)five
    {
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://*21*090-43-137902#"]];

    NSString *phoneNumberString=@"*21*090-43-137902#";
NSString *phoneLinkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumberString];
NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];


      }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [call forwarding in iPhone programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012559/call-forwarding-in-iphone-programmatically)